# Same IE version sending different user agent values from two different machines

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I have seen similar questions in SO but they don't exactly point to the same problem I am facing.

I have two different desktops with same OS (Windows 8) and same version of IE (11.0.9600).
I am trying to connect to the same URL from these two desktops.

However, I notice that two different user-agent values are being submitted from these two IEs.

```
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

and

```
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0)
```

Can someone please help me understand how do I figure out the reason for this?

This issue has implication for me as the portal I am trying to access does not allow the first user-agent value and shows "unsupported browser" message.

Comment: Look at the User-Agent, in the second you have "compatible".
This compatible mode on F12 and its run with Explorer 10 user agent.

Comment: great observation. I added the site in the compatibility list on my browser and it solves the problem. Why don't you post this as answer and I can mark this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the User-Agent, in the second you have "compatible".

This compatible mode on F12 and its run with Explorer 10 user agent.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the compatibility mode in the second instance.As IE is installed along with your windows, it may have been configured automatically in that mode.